# Ajax enabled WCF in MVC returns 404

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm trying to add a WCF service to my MVC project to have a general place to put my ajax methods but when i try to call its' methods simply by browsing to the url (e.g. ../Service.svc/HelloWorld) or calling it with jquery ajax I get a 404 page instead.

If i do the same thing in a webforms project, it works without any problem. What am I doing wrong here? Is this not the best practice place to keep ajax methods? Like i said: I want a general place to keep my ajax methods that might be reused from several views so i dont want to put them in the controller of the view if possible

My code:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1:IService1
{
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string HelloWorld();
}
```

My configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WebApplication1.Service1">
            <endpoint address=""
                      behaviorConfiguration="AJAXEndpoint"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="WebApplication1.IService1" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AJAXEndpoint">
                <webHttp />
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for MVC Web API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a [ServiceRoute](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/09/22/wcf-rest-services-inside-mvc-projects.aspx) in your Global.asax. You have a 404 simply because there are no routes for this request.

For example this could be

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ThePath", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(YourService)));
```

+1 for asp.net Web Api : this is definitely the recommanded way of building a web api in asp.net, especially in an existing mvc project.